# Laravel Livewire data is converted to an array after render

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple livewire component which *initializes* with queried data from SQL. Below is code

```
public $states=[];

public function mount()
{
    $this->states = DB::select("select id,name from hr_states");
}
```

in the view:

```
<select class="mt-1">
    <option>...select...</option>
    @foreach($states as $state)
        <option value="{{$state->id}}" wire:key="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

on the first render, it works well but on any update on page (on other events), it throws error `Attempt to read property "id" on array` pointing to this line `<option value="{{$state->id}}" wire:key="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->name}}`

So I tried rendering as an array `{{$state['id']}}` but that throws error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: cast it to an array with `->toArray()` and use it as an array all the time

Comment: it doesn't allow to chain `->toArray()` to `DB::select()` throwing `Call to a member function toArray() on array`. So the issue is, it says `gettype($this->states)` is `array` but doesn't allow displaying using `{{$state['id']}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
class StateComponent extends Component
{  
    public function render()  
    { 
        $states = DB::table("select * from states")->get();  
        return view('livewire.state-component', ['$states'=>$states]) ;
    }   
}
```

in the view:

```
<select class="mt-1"> 
    <option>...select...</option> 
    @foreach($states as $state)
        <option value="{{$state->id}}" wire:key="{{$state->id}}"> 
              {{$state->name}}</option>  
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue before & my approach is using a ternary operator in the blade.

so, instead of using

```
    {{$state->id}}
```

I use the null coalesce operator

```
    {{$state->id ?? $state['id']}}
```

By doing this, if it cannot find the 'state' object with attribute 'id', it will search for the 'state' array with key 'id'.

This is only a workaround method. still can't figure out how to prevent it from converting to an array after render.

Comment: The `??` operator is not the ternary operator. It is the null coalesce operator, which returns the first non-null argument. In your case it works as you describe, where it returns  `$state->id` if that exists, else it returns `$state['id']`.

The null coalesce operator is only available in PHP 7.0 or later.

Comment: thanks a lot @BrokenBinary for pointing out all the details. appreciate it a lot ‍♂️.